# Append an image to a div using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, for-loop, append

[Currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXMwU.png) I want to append an image in a div that is being created in a for loop. The image will be appended to the #hiddenItems. I can't figure out how to place a div holding an image within this for loop. I want to place a pin icon on a description box that is created through this for loop.

Is there a way to do this? Is this question clear enough? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
for(var x = 0; x < itemIDs.length; x++) {
  console.log("x: " + x);
  $('<div class="' + itemClass1s[x] + ' hidden" id="hidden' + itemIDs[x] + '"  style="left: ' + itemXs[x] + 'px top:' + itemYs[x] + 'px;">' + itemContents[x] +'<img src="pin_red.png">' + '</div>').appendTo($('#hiddenItems'));
}
```

Comment: try to use this http://api.jquery.com/append/ and the docu

Comment: Why inside this loop? You create multiple images then, don't you just want ONE image appended to #hiddenItems? Or do I get this wrong?

Comment: You're missing a `;` between the CSS statements in the `style` attribute. Also the jQuery object in `appendTo()` is redundant; just use a string selector

Comment: I was putting it in this loop because the loop creates description boxes on a map the data come from a XML file. I want to take an image of a pin and append it to the corner of the description boxes that display on the map after a button is pressed. I'm using the pin image to make a more precise showing.

Answer (score -1):

## Solution

Use `append()` on `$('#hiddenItems')`...

```
for(var x = 0; x < itemIDs.length; x++) {
  var $element = $('<div/>');

  // Build the element this way for less headaches
  $element
    .addClass(itemClass1s[x] + ' hidden')
    .attr('id', 'hidden' + itemIDs[x])
    .css({left: itemXs[x] + 'px', top: itemYs[x] + 'px'})
    .html(itemContents[x]);

  $('#hiddenItems').append($element);
}
```